# How to calculate row differences in r when it's not in sequence

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame like this:

```
name    count
 a        3  
 a        5   
 a        8   
 b        2   
 a        9  
 b        7
```

so I want to calculate the row differences group by name. so my code is:

`data%>%group_by(Name)%>%mutate(last_count = lag(count),diff = count - last_count)`

However, I get a result like the below table

```
name    count    last_count   diff
 a        3          NA        NA
 a        5          3         2
 a        8          5         3
 b        2          NA        NA
 a        9          8         1
 b        7          2         5
```

But what I want should look like this:

```
name    count    last_count   diff
 a        3          NA        NA
 a        5          3         2
 a        8          5         3
 b        2          NA        NA
 a        9          NA        NA
 b        7          NA        NA
```

Thanks in advance to whoever can help me fix it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work:

```
> library(dplyr)
> df %>% mutate(last_count = case_when(name == lag(name) ~ lag(count), TRUE ~ NA_real_), 
diff = case_when(name == lag(name) ~ count - lag(count), TRUE ~ NA_real_))
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  name  count last_count  diff
  <chr> <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>
1 a         3         NA    NA
2 a         5          3     2
3 a         8          5     3
4 b         2         NA    NA
5 a         9         NA    NA
6 b         7         NA    NA
>
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `rleid` to create a grouping column based on the adjacent matching values in the 'name' column and then apply the `diff`

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
data %>%
    group_by(grp = rleid(name)) %>% 
    mutate(last_count = lag(count), diff = count - last_count) %>% 
    ungroup %>% 
    select(-grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
#  name  count last_count  diff
#  <chr> <int>      <int> <int>
#1 a         3         NA    NA
#2 a         5          3     2
#3 a         8          5     3
#4 b         2         NA    NA
#5 a         9         NA    NA
#6 b         7         NA    NA
```

---

Or using `base R` with `ave` and `rle`

```
data$diff <-  with(data, ave(count, with(rle(name), 
   rep(seq_along(values), lengths)), FUN = function(x) c(NA, diff(x)))
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(name = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "a", "b"), count = c(3L, 
5L, 8L, 2L, 9L, 7L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -6L))
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply! This works for me as well!